# How to route in ASP.NET Core for deleting error 404 Not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I reorganized my project folders, and I think It could be for the new "Customer area". In visual studio 2019 for mac, it doesn't appear to **add area**, not even in new scaffolding, so I added new folders.

I think the error 404 is because of "routing". I show my folders and code:

[image]

Controller:

```
    namespace BulkyBook.Areas.Customer.Controllers
{
    [Area("Customer")]
    //[Route("Customer/Home/Index/id")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two issues. First, you've made `id` a required route param, so no route without that part will match anything. Second, you've made it so where *only* areas can be routed to. In other words, if there's not an area portion of the URL, then it will fail. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1) tell you how to do all this, and specifically, this is the route config you should have:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "Customer",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    // other endpoints, e.g.
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Comment: I got it, I had to put "endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute()" Thanks for your answer